# How can I get network printer autodiscovery working on a LAN network?

Tags: windows, networking, printer

I am working in a small company running Windows 7 with Active Directory, and we have two self-hosted printers on the network (a Dell 2335dn B&W MFP, and a 2155cn color MFP).  I can connect to these printers just fine on any computer by finding them by IP address and adding them by hand, but it's kind of a pain and I would like new employees (or existing employees with new computers) to be able to just click "Add network printer" in Devices and Printers, select B&W or color, and press go.

I have tried installing the printers on a server and adding them to Active Directory, and they do show up in the automatic scan when I do this, but if I try to connect I get an error:

[image]

Also, the host should be "king", not "kin"--on AD it lists the host correctly.  Again, I can connect and print just fine using IP, and the server that the AD printer is installed on can print with no problems.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: can you connect to the embedded web server of the printer thru a browser via its ip address?

Comment: @Logman Yes, no problem.

Comment: You added the printer (via ip address) to a computer, you went to printer properties and selected "Share this printer". Entered a "Share Name". Make sure it is short (8chars or less) and no spaces. And then checkmarked "List in the directory"?

Comment: @Logman Duh, problem solved--I was trying to add them directly in AD from the administrator end. Post as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add the printer (via ip address) to a computer, go to printer properties and selected "Share this printer". Entered a "Share Name". Make sure it is short (8chars or less) and no spaces. And then checkmarked "List in the directory".